# Why is my primary links class (a:links & a:hover) overriding my newly created unique classes (#footer_links a:links, #footer_links a:hover)

Tags: css, hover, hyperlink

a bit confused and could greatly appreciate some insight:

Currently in our primary CSS file, we have all 'general' links defined as:

```
`a:link {color:#da0000; text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color: #CA0000;}
a:hover {color: #000000; text-decoration: underline;}
a:active {color:#da0000;}`
```

However, because there are various sections of the website that I would like to have  *different* colored links, I defined another class to use only in the FOOTER as follows:

```
`.footer_links {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;}

.footer_links a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;}

.footer_links a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;}

.footer_links a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000000;}`
```

However, when I launch the page, the primary link effects override my .footer_links class. This confuses me, as in each footer link, I have defined the class as, class="footer_links" --- because the links are defined by a separate class, I am unsure why its effects are being overridden.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Take a look into Chrome developer tools or Firebug for Firefox. These allow you to right click an element and `inspect` it. In the control panel you will be able to see what styles were applied and their precedence. A great way of debugging your CSS!

Comment: Can you post your html? Or better yet a jsfiddle? Your logic is correct so this should work. http://jsfiddle.net/ZWLqg/

Answer (score 2):

Your rules are wrong, you are putting some rules for the next structure

```
<div class="footer_links"><a> ...
```

if you have an html like

```
<a class="footer_links"> ....
```

you css must look like

```
a.footer_links {}
a.footer_links:hover {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have given the links itself () in your footer the class footer_links.
Right?

If that is the case it cannot work, because you have specified in your CSS that all children of footer_links that are the Element a have a behaviour.

Change it to

```
.footer_links:visited{
 ...
}

.footer_links:hover{
 ...
}
```

When I see it right, that should solve your problem.